# How to iterate through select html options using jQuery depending on option value from another select html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two HTML select elements and I want to:

1. Iterate through the first select element and pick up the value from selected option.
2. Iterate through the second select element and select option which have the same value as a selected value from the first element.

I am using jQuery and this is code which doesn't work.

```
$(document).on("change", "select[name='office_id']", function () {

    var office_id = parseInt($(this).val());

    var options = $(this).parents('tr').find("select[name='phone']").children();

    $(options).each(function() {
        if ($(this).parents('tr').find("select[name='phone']").val() == office_id) {
            $(this).attr('selected', true);
        }
    });
});
```

When I use `$(this).each` which means that `$(this)` is `"select[name='office_id']`, but I want to use jQuery to select phone options and iterate through them.
`$(options).each` doesn't work.

Comment: post your html also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).on("change", "select[name='office_id']", function () {

    var office_id = parseInt($(this).val());
    var options = $(this).parents('tr').find("select[name='phone'] option");

    options.filter(function(){
       return ($(this).attr('value')== office_id);
    }).prop('selected',true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:You can iterate all option and select or deselect option as per matched office id

```
$(document).on("change", "select[name='office_id']", function () {

    var office_id = parseInt($(this).val());
    var options = $(this).parents('tr').find("select[name='phone'] option");

    options.each(function(){
       //select or deselect option as per match office_id
       $(this).attr('selected', $(this).val()==office_id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below answer

```js
$(function() {
  $("#office_id").change(function() { 
    $("#phone option").each(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr("value") == $("#office_id").val()){
         $("#phone").val($("#office_id").val());
        }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="office_id">
<option value="1">Test</option>
<option value="2">Test1</option>
<option value="3">Test2</option>
<option value="4">Test3</option>
</select>

<select id="phone"> 
<option value="5">Temp</option>
<option value="6">Temp1</option>
<option value="7">Temp2</option>
<option value="8">Temp3</option>
<option value="3">Test2</option>
<option value="4">Test3</option>
</select>
```